# How to loop through a class instance?

Tags: python, class

I was asked this question.  Given the code:

```
class MockList:
    ...code_here...

for i in MockList():
    print(i)
```

Expected result of for loop:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you implement an [`__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method, you can do this functionality:

#### Code:

```
class MockList:

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(range(1, 6))
```

#### Test Code:

```
for i in MockList():
    print(i)
```

#### Results:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```